# How can I unifiy .mdf database connection string across all users?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm developing Windows Forms application and I'm facing a problem that I use connection string path to the `.mdf` SQL Server database file on my computer but when running the app on another computer the path will be different.

How can I figure it our programmatically?

Comment: store connection string app.config and read it from there

Comment: Why don't you choose a machine on your lan, install sql server express and add the database to the server instance? Then your `customers` don't need to know the path to your machine

Comment: I want to use local database its very simple app with few users .. but how can I get the connection string to store it ? from my experience I get it from the properties in visual studio but how can I do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Do as Ehsan suggested and store the connection string in app.config and then use the ConfigurationManager class to accomplish what you are after.

Here is a example on MSDN that shows how to do it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx